# Einstein Vision issue when Creating the DataSet

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

I am trying to create a data-set using Einstein Vision API by following this [trail](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/build-a-cat-rescue-app-that-recognizes-cat-breeds/cat-recognition-app-create-train-dataset). So i have successfully created the dataset by providing the following URL: https://developer.salesforce.com/files/Cats.zip

Then i have downloaded the same file and stored it in Google Drive(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ngNA1bgmFZMrtD6NSOGLoPNp2WLn6gS1) and tried to create a dataset. But i am not able to create the dataset.

please let me know what i am missing here

Comment: Could you kindly tell us what is the error/issue you're facing while creating the dataset?

Comment: @kamal, i could not see any error, the dataset is created with the name as "dataset" instead of the folder name also the dataset is empty. It has n't loaded with any images.

Comment: Should u not use this address of zip: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ngNA1bgmFZMrtD6NSOGLoPNp2WLn6gS1/view

Comment: @Ayup, Same issue. Except the url which has provided in trail nothing seems working. But i could able to do it from local which is only having 50MB limitation

Comment: I had same issue but i found that it was url issue... may be u re-upload ur local file to google then try again also that file must be publicly available ...

Comment: I have tried with so many type of URL's in Gdrive, nothing seems working. Fortunately it is working in onedrive. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Even if I am not 100% sure where the error lies in your case I'd bet you ran into the same problem as I, as everybody.

Check this thread and see if this resembles your problem: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000UbjnQAC

Rene the creator of the module recommends that you redo some steps if you are stuck.

I'd also recommend you open a GitHub issue in his repo which is the base of this Trailhead:
https://github.com/muenzpraeger/salesforce-einstein-vision-apex/issues

Comment: Yeah Robert, i ran into the same situation. After trying for so many times, finally the URL from one drive is working. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a very similar issue before with Dropbox. See [Einstein Vision Dataset creation issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/189158/102).

The Dataset URL that you provide to the Einstein Vision API needs to resolve to the actual zip file without any additional HTTP redirects or authentication requirements. There is no mechanism for the Einstein Vision API to send cookies or user credentials to download the zip file.

While Google Docs and Dropbox appear to have additional authentication or redirect requirements, OneDrive will successfully serve a zip file to the API. You may need to get the actual URL that the sharing link resolves to.